# Symfony2: establish a model relationship by id

Tags: symfony

I'm building an API on Symfony2 an I have a Model ItemOrder with a ManyToOne relationship to a Model Item. I have a few Items in my database, and I want to add an ItemOrder that points to an Item that is already in the database, and whose id I know. So my first approach is this:

```
$item = new Item();
$item->setId(2);

$orderItem = new OrderItem();
$orderItem->setItem($item);

$em->persist($orderItem);
$em->flush();
```

However, Symfony2 understand that I'm trying to create a new item. I know that a valid approach would be fetching the Item object with the entity manager, and then assign it to the ItemOrder, but I think it's a not very efficient way of doing it.

So how should this be done?

Comment: Why not `$orderItem->setItemId(2);` (if you are really sure about your ItemId 2) ?

Comment: And how should I implement that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [Partial Reference](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html).

```
$item = $em->getPartialReference('Item', 2);

$orderItem = new OrderItem();
$orderItem->setItem($item);

$em->persist($orderItem);
$em->flush();
```

However, please read the [What is the problem?](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html#what-is-the-problem) paragraph carefully, it might be safer to query for full entities by ids instead.

### getPartialReference() vs getReference()

I've originally also found what forgottenbas linked, but I don't think it's the correct solution.

These two methods seem to be almost identical and both are referenced in official documentation.
Seems that only reasonable way to determine which is best is by looking directly into source code: [getReference()](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L435-#L479) and [getPartialReference()](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L481-#L521).

Straight up you will notice that `getPartialReference()` is better documented with a clear description of a use case that exactly matches yours:

```
 * The use-cases for partial references involve maintaining bidirectional associations
 * without loading one side of the association or to update an entity without loading it.
```

If you investigate the code for `getReferece()` you will notice that in some cases it **will** result in a database call:

```
if ($class->subClasses) {
    return $this->find($entityName, $sortedId);
}
```

and finally, `getPartialReference()` marks partial reference as read-only, better defining it's purpose:

```
$this->unitOfWork->markReadOnly($entity);
```

Comment: But this way you're accessing the database anyway, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

You can create special reference object. More info see on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382170/doctrine-2-inserting-an-entity-with-associations-is-there-a-way-to-just-use-th) question

```
$item = $em->getReference('FQCNBundle:Item', 2);

$orderItem = new OrderItem();
$orderItem->setItem($item);

$em->persist($orderItem);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: I would advise against this method in this case, see my update for explanation.

Comment: You can see good explanation about the difference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486662/doctrine-entity-remove-vs-delete-query-performance-comparison

Comment: Did you actually read my explanation? Are you sure `->getReference()` functionality (i.e. ability to lazy load & attach event listeners) is the use case for author?

Comment: There is no way to understand what's going on further by that piece of code