# Referencing foreign keys entirely by ID when creating entities in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a set of normalised entities (psuedocode):

```
User (id, name)
Subscription (id, user_id, magazine_id, internal_reference)
Magazine (id, name)
```

Normally, creating a new Subscription in the standard Doctrine way would be easy:

```php
// The internal reference is just to emphasize that I have logic inside the constructor that sets an important value
$subscription = new Subscription($textThatWillBeMangledToGenerateInternalReference);
$subscription->setMagazine($magazine);
$subscription->setUser($user);
$this->_em->persist($subscription);
$this->_em->flush();
```

In my use case however I currently have a `Magazine` entity but 1000 UserIDs.

Potential solutions:

1. Running something like `SELECT * FROM User WHERE id IN (:userIds)`. This would be a rather horrible workaround given that I have no desire for that data and it'll make no difference to the the queries that `->persist` will fire
2. Creating some kind of psuedo entity? Perhaps something like `$user = new User($userId);` then using that. *If* this works (which I'm unsure about), this would be horrible because the UserID is a GeneratedValue, so adding any form of external setter for it would again be a rather horrible hack
3. Stepping over the doctrine entity system entirely and poking data in via PDO. This has advantages of avoiding the relatively slow nature of the Doctrine one-by-one `INSERT` system but it means I'd be skipping the `$internalReference` logic inside the Subscription entity. This can of course be moved elsewhere, but I'd like to try and understand if there's an idiomatic way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an embarassingly short period of time I found the answer I was after [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486662/doctrine-entity-remove-vs-delete-query-performance-comparison).

You can use the entity manager to create a partial reference to essentially allow a (relatively) clean way of doing method 2

Example in the context of my question:

```php
$subscription = new Subscription($textThatWillBeMangledToGenerateInternalReference);
$subscription->setMagazine($magazine);
$subscription->setUser($this->_em->getPartialReference(User::class, array('id' => $userId)););
$this->_em->persist($subscription);
$this->_em->flush();
```

Comment: What is the difference from getReference() method? I was about to suggest that.

Comment: It looks like the difference between partial/non partial reference is only really relevant if you're doing very icky looking bi-directional hackery: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/2314